# Dropdown menu columns

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar, multiple-columns

I would like to have columns within my drop down menu but I don't know how I've tried integrating existing ones from the web but they don't work. I would like to have the column portion in three separate columns so it is not on large drop down going down and rather a box which appears containing three columns

```css
/*Navigation Bar*/

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #FB724C;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  background-color: inherit;
  height: 40px;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #B64321;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #F4DDD0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="Index.html">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Tech 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Apple <i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Android <i class="fa fa-android"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Computers <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Drones <i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Photography <i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
      <a href="#">TVs <i class="fa fa-"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="Subscription.html">Subcription</a>
  <a href="#news">About Us</a>
  <a href="#news">Contact</a>
  <a style="float:right" href="#Sign Up">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a style="float:right" href="#Log In">Log in <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a snippet with flexboxes and left yours to compare both, feel free to check it out !

The plus side is that the flexboxes will adapt no matter the width, or number of items. And they automatically center the elements when given the right properties !

And no more float left or right, flexboxes handle that pretty easily.

```css
/*Navigation Bar*/

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
}



.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  background-color: inherit;
  height: 40px;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #B64321;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #F4DDD0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* ======================================================= */

.navbar-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.left, .right {
  display: flex;
}

.active-2 {
  background-color: #FB724C;
}

.navbar-2 a {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 13px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-2 a:hover { opacity: 0.8; }

.dropdown-content-2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-2 {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.spacer { flex: 1 1 auto; }

.dropdown-2:hover .dropdown-content-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.dropdown-content-2 a {
  flex: 1 1 33%;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  color: black;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="Index.html">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Tech 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Apple <i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Android <i class="fa fa-android"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Computers <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Drones <i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Photography <i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
      <a href="#">TVs <i class="fa fa-"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="Subscription.html">Subcription</a>
  <a href="#news">About Us</a>
  <a href="#news">Contact</a>
  <a style="float:right" href="#Sign Up">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a style="float:right" href="#Log In">Log in <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>

<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<div class="navbar-2">
  <div class="left">
    <a class="active-2" href="Index.html">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown-2">
      <a href="#tech" class="dropdown-2">Tech</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content-2">
        <a href="#">Apple <i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a>
        <a href="#">Android <i class="fa fa-android"></i></a>
        <a href="#">Computers <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></a>
        <a href="#">Drones <i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
        <a href="#">Photography <i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
        <a href="#">TVs <i class="fa fa-"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="Subscription.html">Subcription</a>
    <a href="#news">About Us</a>
    <a href="#news">Contact</a>
  </div>
  
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  
  <div class="right">
    <a href="#Sign Up">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#Log In">Log in <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

place this code snippet where you want your dropdown.

```
    <td class="dropdown">
    <a>Dropdown Table</a>
<dev id="rows">
    <tr><ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
    </ul></tr>
    <tr><ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
    </ul></tr>
    <tr><ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
    </ul></tr>
    </dev>
    </td>

    /* CSS /*
    .dropdown .rows {display:none}
    .dropdown:hover .rows {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try added to `.dropdown-content` css properties: `column-count: 3;` and `max-height: 150px;`.

```css
/*Navigation Bar*/

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #FB724C;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  background-color: inherit;
  height: 40px;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #B64321;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  column-count: 3;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #F4DDD0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="Index.html">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Tech 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Apple <i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Android <i class="fa fa-android"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Computers <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Drones <i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
      <a href="#">Photography <i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
      <a href="#">TVs <i class="fa fa-"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="Subscription.html">Subcription</a>
  <a href="#news">About Us</a>
  <a href="#news">Contact</a>
  <a style="float:right" href="#Sign Up">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a style="float:right" href="#Log In">Log in <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```